# How to write a script that navigates to the feature and disable it?

Tags: android, adb

I want to disable a feature that is listed in the cellular network settings in our android devices.

I tried the following through the ADB
start activity com.android.phone/.MobileNetworkSettings
adb shell input keyevent 20 & ADB shell input keyevent 23

The code is working fine and it disables the feature, however, I need to apply this to bulk devices through MDM and it only supports JAVA scripts. Is there is a way to write a script that navigates to the feature and disable it?

Our devices OS is android 6.01

Answer (score 0):

Not an MDM solution but a better alternative to plain ADB using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (C) 2013-2019  Diego Torres Milano
Culebra v20.2.0
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
"""


import sys

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

_s = 5


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

device.startActivity(component='com.android.phone/.MobileNetworkSettings')
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)

vc.dump(window=-1)
mobile_data = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('Mobile data')
vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('android:id/switch_widget', mobile_data.parent).touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('OK').touch()
```

Notice that you can record scripts like this one just using [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) pointing and clicking on the device representation. Also, this can be run on multiple devices concurrently.